# Как ограничить область видимости переменных в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть несколько кусков кода, которые используют переменные с одинаковыми именами:

```
var owl = $('.banner__carousel');

...

var owl = $('.contact__carousel');
```

Раньше, чтобы не было конфликтов, я просто оборачивал каждый такой кусок в

```
$(function() { ... });
```

Пока не узнал, что это сокращение для

```
$(document).on('ready', function() { ... });
```

Если ли какой-либо другой способ ограничить видимость переменной (кроме как оборачивать ее в другую функцию и давать ей еще одно название).

Comment: Ну область видимости то ограничивается обычным `var'ом` внутри функции, соответственно объявляя переменную локально. А неймспейсы в JS не завезли, емнип. В чем проблема то, 1-2 символа дописать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В стандарте ECMAScript 5 такой возможности нет. Переменные, объявленные через var, ограничены только телом функции, в которой они объявлены.

В стандарте  ECMAScript 6 стало возможным объявлять переменные через let и const. Такие переменные видны только внутри контейнера `{}`, причем только после своего объявления.

Comment: Может возможно обернуть каждый такой кусок кода в безымянную функцию и сразу ее вызвать?

Comment: Я бы все-таки рекомендовал вам воспользоваться советом SLy_huh и использовать разные названия для разных переменных в теле одной функции. Тут еще важно помнить, что объявленная в конце функции через var переменная видна сразу во всем теле функции, в том числе, и в самом начале. Если вам все-таки хочется одинаково названных переменных, сделайте разные сделайте разные функции и просто вызывайте их где вам удобнее.